# Git diff tool reset to git default

Tags: git, command-line, diff

I accidentally changed my git diff tool and it was not actually installed and I have no permissions over the machine. How can I revert to the original tool that shows changes in command line? It may sound silly but I have not been able to make a single diff and I have found no information about this, only on how to change it to others than the default. I have tried to unset the variable but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This depends on how you changed your git diff tool config when run `git config`.

- If you used --system, your configuration will have been written to system-wide $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig
- If you used --global, your configuration will have been written to global ~/.gitconfig file
- The default is to assume the config file of the current repository, .git/config unless defined  otherwise with GIT_DIR and GIT_CONFIG

Try to find diff.tool configure value in above files and delete it.

Comment: If you use `git config --list --show-origin` it will tell you where it derived each individual config entry from.